# Using a value to set an object's key in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Inside a loop, I'm trying to set the value as the object's key. Not sure how to do this:

```
@user = {"username"=>"123", "full_name"=>"John Doe"}

@account = Account.new
@user.keys.each { |key|
  @account.key = @user[key]
}
```

That returns an error of: NoMethodError: undefined method `key='

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function calls in Ruby act like message-passing. So what you are looking for is [send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send).

The `@account` object in your example is not a Hash like `@user`, it is a Class instance.

But Rails has an even better way to initialize a Model with attributes:

```
@account = Account.new(username: '123', full_name: 'John Doe')
```

In a Rails controller, these are usually in the `params` hash if you wrote your form correctly:

```
@account = Account.new(params[:user])
```

If you must do it manually, you can:

```
@account = Account.new

# set all attributes at once
@account.attributes = @user

# this also works, but it's the least desirable
@user.each {|key, value| @account.send("#{key}=", value) }
```

The last example works because `@account.key = value` is actually syntactic sugar for a method call: `@account.key=(value)`

I highly recommend reading through [Rails Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) and building your forms how it suggests.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is to make @account.username be 123, and @account.full_name be "John Doe", right?

Does Account have a `username` and `fullname` attribute? Does it have a `key` attribute? It obviously don't have `key`, because that's why you're getting that error.

If Account does have `username` and `fullname`, then just do:

```
@account.update_attributes!(@user)
```

If it doesn't, then I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way;

```
@user = {"username" => "123", "full_name" => "John Doe"}
@account = Account.new
@user.keys.each{|key| eval("@account.#{key} = @user[key]")}
```